# Unknown "GG6M" smd integrated circuit

Tags: microcontroller, integrated-circuit, surface-mount

I bought 6 month ago a controller for a screen (T.VST59.031) https://fr.aliexpress.com/store/product/Free-Shipping-T-VST59-031-V59-universal-definition-LCD-TV-panels-HDMI-LCD-driver-board/1270386_32510541373.html

Everything worked fine until now, one 5-pin integrated circuit broke. 
I managed to get it out of the board and it was written on it "GG6M". But I can't manage to find anything about it on the internet.
I know it has something to do with the transmission of the power signal because the red led indicating that the screen is powered but off is working, but if I try to turn on the screen using the IR controller or the power key, the led stays red and the screen doesn't start.

Here are some screens : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zf6bc.jpg

1. The whole board
2. A close view of where the integrated circuit was after I took it off
3. A close view of the integrated circuit before I took it off
4. Another view of the area where the circuit was

Do you have any idea of what it could be or how I could find it out ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It *could* be a LC3406 Synchronous buck converter: datasheet [here](http://www.s-manuals.com/pdf/datasheet/l/c/lc3406_leadchip.pdf).

According to the datasheet, this chip is in a SOT-23-5 package, which really looks like what you have, and has a "GG" marking followed by two characters indicating year and week, which is consistent with what you have.

We see a big inductor next to the chip, two resistors that look like a feedback network, and what certainly is an input capacitor, and if we check the tracks layout on your photos, it is all consistent with the pinout described in the datasheet.

For info: I went [on this site](http://www.s-manuals.com/smd) to find this information. But there are plenty of other sites/databooks referencing component markings.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. After two days of intense searching on internet, you're my unique solution so far. I think I'll buy this component and try it out. At worst I will break the board but it's either that or I throw it so it's worth the try. Also, I found some other pictures of this board on internet, and this integrated circuit have a different name every time (not starting with GG). I will keep you updated

Comment: Yes, the marking codes are not the safest way to identify a component you have no clue what it is. A possibility is that, since it is a rather common type of component, they have multiple sources from multiple manufacturers for this chip, and the marking end up being different depending on the production batch. But if the board is dead, it is worth trying.

Comment: I would be very surprised if that's not a buck converter (or less likely, a boost converter)

Comment: Hey all quick update : I just tried it and everything works fine so far ! Thanks for your help @dim, you were my last chance !